# Нужно ли выделять память при статической инициализации массива структур?

Tags: linux, c

У меня виснет программа при работе куска кода, использующего этот массив.
К сожалению, обрисовать все тут не смогу, т.к. очень большой кусок кода.

У меня есть структура:

```
struct element {
   char *one;
   char *two;
};
```

Далее идет массив таких структур (статически объявлен):

```
struct element array[] = {
   {"1 field", "2 field"},
   {"3 field", "4 field"},
   {"5 field", "6 field"}
};
```

С одной стороны, массив объявлен статически - зачем выделять память. С другой - поля структуры ведь указатели (память выделяется под указатели, а не строки).

Есть ли тут ошибка?

Comment: Уточните, *виснет* или *валится*? Если все же виснет, т.е. не ждет ввода и не завершается, то скорее всего где-то бесконечный цикл (например, в каком-то из условий по ошибке вместо `a == b` набили `a = b`) и к данным в вопросе ошибка отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть ли тут ошибка?

Ошибки тут нет, но есть подозрительный момент.

Присваиваемые указатели ведут на константные строки, что означает, что менять символы внутри строк нельзя. Во-первых, неизвестно, объединил ли компилятор строки, т. е. несколько структур могут получить одни и те же указатели, если строки различны. Во-вторых, область памяти с этими строками, скорее всего, помечена как readonly.

Comment: Строки программа по идее не должна менять, да и кода их меняющего нет. А как проверить, не объединил ли их компилятор? Как протестировать возможные неполадки?

Comment: @MaximGusev, сравнить указатели на равенство. Но зачем, если нигде не делается попытка их изменить?

Comment: Ну если структуры все разные, то и указатели не могут быть одни на разные структуры тогда, я по, крайней мере, так считаю...

Comment: @MaximGusev, не структуры, строки. В примере ты используешь 2 различные строки по 3 раза каждую - компилятор, вероятно, выделит память только под 2 строки (а не под 6) и поместит во все 3 структуры одинаковые указатели.

Comment: @MaximGusev, да: http://ideone.com/jgFu1H

Comment: Ааа... Извините - сейчас исправлю - тут все 6 строк разные

Comment: @MaximGusev, в любом случае, это не важно, если нет записи в эти строки. А если есть, то это тоже не важно, ибо всё равно UB.

Comment: Но если я не пытаюсь изменять эти строки, то и UB не должно быть?

Comment: @MaximGusev, не должно.

Answer (score 0):

Но ведь память вы уже выделили - ведь эти строки где-то же располагаются :)

Так что все в порядке, больше ничего выделять не надо.

Другое дело, что эти строки, хотя C формально разрешает менять (скажем, менять отдельные символы на другие), поступать так категорически не рекомендуется.

Comment: Спасибо, значит ошибка не тут.

Comment: Вы их не пытаетесь менять? Они используются как константные?

Comment: Мне их не нужно менять. Да. Программа их не меняет.

Comment: Тогда ошибка не тут.

Comment: @Harry: "C формально разрешает менять" - это откуда вы такое взяли? Язык С открытым текстом *запрещает* менять строковые литералы, в том смысле что попытка изменения ведет к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: @AnT Книга **C IN A NUTSHELL Second Edition**, стр. 48: *"Although C does not strictly prohibit modifying string literals, you should not
attempt to do so."* Грубо говоря, код компилируется. Выполняется ли - дело другое :) А раз компилируется - значит, формального запрета нет... Например - http://ideone.com/X0Trf9 - ошибка выполнения, не компиляции...

Comment: @Harry: Ну, во-первых, это конечно вопрос терминологии: считать ли UB "запретом". Во-вторых, в общем случае "код компилируется" - это не аргумент. Язык С содержит определенное количество запретов, которые не требуют диагностирования компилятором. Это однако не значит, что "формального запрета нет". Это значит, что запрет есть, но компилятор не сумел его продиагностировать, воспользовавшись разрешением стандарта "не париться". В-третьих, одним из допустимых проявлений UB является именно отказ компилятора компилировать код. Ваш компилятор проглотил, а какой-то другой "особо умный" - откажется :)

Comment: @AnT UB - это и есть формальное отсутствие запрета :)

Comment: @Harry Ну то есть вам нравится трактовать понятие "запрета" именно так и вы именно это изначально имели в виду. Нет проблем. Я же предпочитаю включать в понятие "запрета" и UB, в том числе потому, что реализациям разрешается диагностировать UB на стадии компиляции.

Comment: @AnT Ну вот и ладушки :) Если вам нравится так - без вопросов. Но для меня UB - это означает "ты уже большой, решай сам..."